# Losing CSS for 0.1s when redirecting pages in Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I build a simple app using Ruby on Rails,
and I dont know why when I go to other pages, the css will be lost for 0.1s
The page will be displayed without any styling for a really short period of time and load the css afterwards.
How can I fix this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is there some reliance on jquery/js to add classes etc?  Since many times you'll only load that after the page is loaded that would be a starting point if you have js in your app.

Comment: Its known as a Flash of Unstyled Content (FOUC) and there are quite a few potential causes. I would try a HTML validator and make sure there are no errors in the browser console.

Comment: also possible that the order of your asset is causing that i.e. the stylesheet should be loaded before the page.